# NSPredicate for NSString With Custom Format

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nspredicate

I'd like to use NSPredicate to match NSString but I'm having trouble getting started. My goal is to match certain NSStrings that contain the formats of.

1. be---
2. be-tt
3. -----g

If anyone has simple examples that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a NSPredicate with `+predicateWithBlock:` with your own comparaison code.

OR using [regex](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001794-SW9) (maybe the best solution):

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES '(be...)|(be.tt)|(.....g)'"]
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do this would be to use the `LIKE` operator.  With this string operator, you can use the special character `*` and `?`.  `*` means "0 or more characters", and `?` means "exactly one character".  So you could do:

```
NSPredicate * p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF LIKE %@ OR SELF LIKE %@ OR SELF LIKE %@", @"be???", @"be?tt", @"?????g"];
NSLog(@"%d", [p evaluateWithObject:@"beast"]); //logs "1"
```

(@benoît makes a good observation in his answer that this can also be accomplished with a regular expression [the `MATCHES` operator], which can cut down on the length of the predicate format string)

Comment: How would you go about matching those strings above if the number of '-' could vary?

Comment: @aahrens "*" = 0 or more characters, "?*" = 1 or more characters, "??*" = 2 or more characters...  So "be*" matches any word that starts with "be".  "be?*" matches any word that starts with "be" and is at least 3 letters long, etc.